# `Configure Logcat Formatting Options` has no effect

Tags: android-studio, logcat

Android Studio **2021.3.1.17** > `Configure Logcat Formatting Options` > `Modify Views` > Uncheck `Show repeated tags` > Uncheck `Show repeated package names` > `[OK]`.

Despite this, **Repeated** tags and and package names **continue to be displayed**, even after restarting IDE.

Even the simple option to display Time instead of Datetime does not work:

[image: Logcat Format Show timestamp]

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to upgrade to:

`Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1`